# How to add SKU and remove product title from WooCommerce url?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

My current url structure is this:

*shop/category/article-name*

I would like to change it to;

*shop/category/sku*

Unfortunately my regex doesn't seem to work properly as only a few products don't give a 404. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpse33551_post_type_link', 1, 3);

function wpse33551_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
   $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sku', true );
   $categories = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');

    if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ){
        return home_url( 'shop/' . $categories[0]->slug . '/' . $post_meta );
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}


add_action( 'init', 'wpse33551_rewrites_init' );

function wpse33551_rewrites_init(){
   $prodCatArgs = ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat'];
   $wooCats = get_categories($prodCatArgs);
   $catSlugs = [];
   foreach($wooCats as $wooCat) {
       $catSlugs[] = $wooCat->slug;
   }
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'shop/^('.implode('|', $catSlugs).')/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)',
        'index.php?post_type=product&category=$matches[1]&product=$matches[2]',
        'top' );
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this if you intend on submitting the site to search engines. Product titles are a much better form of SEO than a SKU which effectively means nothing.

Comment: It's not my choice really. I'm doing it for a client and they insist.